# Creating images from integer-array

Tags: kotlin

I want to add some images to RecycleView, for this I created an array like below,

```
<integer-array name="main_menu_category_image">
    <item>@drawable/plane/item>
    <item>@drawable/auto</item>
    <item>@drawable/tools</item>
    <item>@drawable/computer</item>
</integer-array>
```

After that I'm trying to pass these Int image values to a variable for RecycleView.

var main_menu_images = resources.getIntArray(R.array.main_menu_category_image)

But the problem is, when I check from debug console, "main_menu_images"' all array member's value is 0.

How can I solve this?

Regards.

var main_menu_images = resources.getIntArray(R.array.main_menu_category_image)

Answer (score 0):

Use obtainTypedArray

```
var images = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.main_menu_category_image)
imageView.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(position, defaultvaule)) 
 //position = 0 to anything upto your ArarySize 
 //defaultvalue=-1
```

Comment: Should I put in these lines in "onBindViewHolder" function? Or main activity? Thanks!